# My tiles generated with osm2pgsql look weird?

Tags: openstreetmap, tile, osm2pgsql

This is continuation of this thread:
[Error while importing big file in osm2pgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731195/error-while-importing-big-file-in-osm2pgsql)

same server, same code, same me :-) just .osm file that I used is different.

So I downloaded .osm file from https://www.openstreetmap.org just for Tuam town (Ireland). It worked, I don't know why, maybe because this file is not binary but XML or maybe because it is not so huge? So first question is why it worked at all and second question which refer to title of my issue is WHY do generated tiles look so WEIRD - streets look fragmented. Here is an example tile:

[Tuam 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbNay.png)

Please help

Comment: Are you using the newest osm2pgsql version? If random things are missing then it could be a problem with missing support for 64 bit IDs.

Comment: This is first thing which I want to do now - to try different version.
I downloaded it from here: customdebug.com/osm/osm2pgsql.zip - is this newest version? Which download do you suggest? I don't know what 64 bit IDs are.

Comment: The zip content says this is a very old osm2pgsql version from Dec 17, 2012. New versions are available at https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql. But not for Windows, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Windows instead or consider using a Linux system. You can read about 64 bit IDs here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/64-bit_Identifiers. Tools without proper 64 bit ID support can't handle newer nodes, ways and relations properly. The wiki says the minimum required osm2pgsql version is 0.81.1 (13th of September, 2012) but there have been lots of bug fixes since then.

Comment: I used other version of osm2pgsql form here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63393258/osm2pgsql_testRelease.zip
which was found here:
http://awcull.com/2015/09/30/postgis-osm2pgsql-windows.html
It worked !
It says: osm2pgsql SVN version 0.85-win-cmake (64bit id space)
Now it looks good,  but symbols are not included. Why ? :(
Also I am thinking about compiling it from newest sources. Sorry for such a dumb questions, but where do I find SVN URL ??

Comment: Great to hear. osm2pgsql has no SVN repository but is hosted in a GIT repository instead at github. See my previous comment.

Comment: Where can I find latest build of osm2pgsql for Windows ?

Comment: There are no official builds for Windows as far as I know.

Comment: I found it: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/history I got information here: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/675